# How to contol KeyEvent in Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

[image]

With the window declared with CustomWidget as super class: `class App(CustomWidget)` hitting Alt+A properly prints 'keyPressEvent: Alt + a' message.

But the KeyEvent functionality is broken when the CustomWidget is assigned to window with setCentralWidget() or is set with layer.addWidget(widget). What is missing in a code?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class CustomWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.AltModifier:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_A:
                print 'keyPressEvent: Alt + a'
        # super(CustomWidget, self).keyPressEvent(event)

class App(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent) 
        centralWidget = CustomWidget(self) 

        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        mainLayout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        centralWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)

        widget = CustomWidget(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = App()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget must have focus to receive the event.  Make sure you call setFocusPolicy() to have the CustomWidget accept and maintain focus after creating the window.

[QWidget, keyPressEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent)

[QWidget, setFocusPolicy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop)

Comment: Thanks! I posted it as a solution as well!

Answer (score 0):

## Working Solution:

Important: At the end of GroupBox' keyPressEvent() method we have to pass the Event up to the super. Or the Event will not get propagated to the parent widget: `super(QtGui.QGroupBox, self).keyPressEvent(event)`

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus) 

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_T:
                print 'MainWindow: Control + t'
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_M:
                print 'MainWindow: Control + m'

class GroupBox(QtGui.QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QGroupBox.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus) 

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_T:
                print 'GroupBox: Control + t'
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_S:
                print 'GroupBox: Control + s'
        super(QtGui.QGroupBox, self).keyPressEvent(event)

class App(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        MainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent) 
        centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self) 

        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        mainLayout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        centralWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)

        groupBox = GroupBox(self)
        mainLayout.addWidget(groupBox)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = App()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```